# Can I use the same sockaddr_in in TCP and UDP?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, udp

In my serveur, I bind the TCP and UDP on two different ports.
I first connect my Client with TCP (via accept, etc)

Then I want to use UDP to communicate between my server and my client.
So I tried to use the same `sockaddr_in` like that :

```
void AUDPMonitor::sendMessage(Message &msg)
{
  for (ISocket *socket: *_fdListClients)
  {
    if (msg.getClientId() == socket->getSock())
    {
      UDPSocket *UdpSocket = reinterpret_cast<UDPSocket *>(socket);
      UdpSocket->send(msg, socket->getUserAddr());
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

The `_fdListClients` is a vector of Socket I got from the TCP connexion.
There is no error messages but my client doesn't receive anything.

So I want to know if it's possible to use the same sockaddr_in or if it's impossible.

Edit : When I accept the client socket

```
  socklen_t     client_sin_len;
  sockaddr_in   *client_sin = new sockaddr_in;

  client_sin_len = sizeof(sockaddr_in   );
  std::cout << "New User ! " << std::endl;
  if ((cs = accept(fd, reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr *>(client_sin), &client_sin_len)) == -1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the same copy of the `sockaddr_in` for TCP and UDP, but they have to be on different sockets.

A given socket created with `AF_INET` also specifies either `SOCK_STREAM` making TCP or `SOCK_DGRAM` making it UDP.

So if you have this:

```
struct sockaddr_in sin;
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
sin.sin_port = htons(12345);
```

You can pass this to `bind` with a TCP socket to bind to TCP/12345, and you can pass it to `bind` with a UDP socket to bind to UDP/12345.

Comment: It's not when I create the server socket, but when I accept the client socket. I edited my post.

Comment: For UDP, you don't call `accept`.  You need to either use `sendto` to specify the IP/port of the remote end or you need to call `connect`, passing the the client's IP/port, so that `send` knows where to send to.

Comment: @dbush In fact, he wants to use the sockaddr he got from the tcp, and to use them to send a message to his clients in UDP.
For example I accept a client in TCP. I got his sockaddr_in. Then I give this sockaddr_in in the sendto() function.

Comment: @DimitriDanilov For that to work, the UDP port number the client is listening on must be the same as the TCP port number it connects to the server with.  The client must then `bind` the TCP port before calling `connect.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the same SOCAKADDR_IN structure for a TCP or UDP server or client but whenever you want to use it for a different one you should change the values of port and address because servers cannot be bound to the same port.

so if we have two remote stations running a TCP server and a UDP Server then the client to connect them:

```
SOCKET servTcp; // a remote bound and listing tcp socket waiting for remote clients through the blocking function `accept`
SOCKET servUdp; // a remote bound Udp server waiting for clients
```

// for the client:

```
SOCKET clientTcp = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
SOCKET clientUdp = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,  IPPROTO_UDP);

SOCKADDR_IN sa_serv;
sa_serv.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("127.168.0.1");
sa_serv.sin_family = AF_INET;
sa_serv.sin_port   = htons(777);
```

now the socket clientTcp can connect to the remote tcp server using this address structure.

to use the same SOCKADDR_IN structure sa_serv for the the udp server:

as long as the tpc and the udp servers on the same remote machine we only change the port:

```
sa_serv.sin_port   = htons(1000); // the port is unique for servers to bind on.
```

now we the udp socket clientUdp can use use sa_serv to send and receive data from the remote udp serv.

- SOCKADDR_IN is the same for udp and tcp just change the value of port and sometimes address if server.